# php -v and php-fpm -v show different versions of php

Tags: php, macos, nginx, homebrew

I've been struggling with this all night and can't find an answer that fixes it!

I'm on a mac and using homebrew to install php and nginx, I ran the following which show as successful

```
brew install php
brew install nginx
```

no problems so far and I can start both services

```
brew services start nginx
brew services start nginx
```

when I run brew services list I get the following

```
nginx started me /Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php   started me /Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
```

however when trying to run a Wordpress site I get the following error in my nginx log

```
[error] 26099#0: *1 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:8080"
```

I have googled the problem and it seems that it's normally a problem with nginx passing a request to php-fpm, I have checked the user that is running each service to make sure they match, I have done it as both me and both root to no avail.
When I check "brew services list" it shows php in orange which I understand to mean it has actually failed.

I dug a bit further and it seems that if I run 'php -v' I get

```
PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2018 02:08:27) ( NTS )
```

but if I run 'php-fpm -v' I get:

```
PHP 7.1.16 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Mar 31 2018 03:00:16)
```

I believe this is causing me a problem, I have googled it but haven't got any definitive fixes.

Here is another oddity with it:

```
$which php
/usr/local/bin/php
$which php-fpm
/usr/sbin/php-fpm
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to install this on mac os? is this for local development? Why not use docker?

Comment: Just FYI, `/usr/local/bin` is what is installed by **homebrew** whereas `/usr/sbin/php-fm` is the one supplied by Apple with macOS.

Comment: Maybe create a PHP page in the document root directory that calls `phpinfo()` and see how `nginx` sees your PHP settings.

Comment: @amurell please stop asking of people to use docker. This question is completely legitimate, exactly as it is, and you have nothing to discuss about its context.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far @amurrell I don't want to use docker yet as I don't know it well and don't like trying to learn to many things at once! I have found out where homebrew installs php-fpm `/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.9_2/sbin/php-fpm` so I guess my question now is how do I bind the php-fpm command to this location instead of the standard one?

Comment: Fair, I was just curious since production will likely not be a Mac os. Totally valid to learn to set it up on Mac though. My apologies...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay I've now got both `php -v` and `php-fpm -v` returning the same value of php and i did it by running `brew doctor` which told me to run echo `'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin/:$PATH"'`

so now that I have the same versions running and can confirm that php-fpm is running without failing using `lsof -i | grep php-fpm` I'm on to normal problems that people have installing php and nginx on their mac books! So I can rest easy tonight knowing that I am slightly closer to my goal!

I also now have the following

```
$ which php-fpm
/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

Thank you everyone for your time and suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

#### For me, I have the following architecture after installing php (not with brew) but perhaps this will help anyway...

```
ls /etc/php/
5.6  7.0  7.1  7.2
```

#### and I have the following commands available if I type php and tab:

```
php            php-config     php-config7.2  php-fpm7.2     php7.2         phpdismod      phpenmod       phpize         phpize7.2      phpquery
```

### I have a service running specifically for `php-fpm7.2` as seen here:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm status
 * php-fpm7.2 is running
root@xxx:~# sudo service php5.6-fpm status
php5.6-fpm: unrecognized service
root@xxx:~# sudo service php7.1-fpm status
php7.1-fpm: unrecognized service
```

---

The fact you are getting a different version with `php` is because that is the version of php that runs in the command line - and it has different settings than what will happen when you use fpm (passed through from nginx). I don't think the CLI php has much to do with your fpm versions. It could be that brew's repositories for php are only up to date for fpm 7.16.. I think I might be installing my PHP from a ppa but I cannot recall off the top of my head.

Comment: you might try brew install php@7.2 - but I am not sure since I don't use a mac...

Comment: this looks like it might be my only option as another night has been lost to trying to get it working, I'm not great on a mac so apologies if it's a simple question but how do I set up a service? (I did google it quickly but didn't get very far)